What is OS Fingerprint during boot screen?
During the boot of an unlocked device, it displays "OS Fingerprint:" with some random string.

What does this string represent? Additionally, is there a way to safely change it? I know if you disable verity, 'N/A' will be displayed.

Based on the shown hexadecimal value it could be a CRC value. Thus it could be the CRC of the vbmeta partition or of the vbmeta signature.
